# laravel: how to pass a parameters to a function in model?

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 5.5 / php 7.2 /

for example, I have a function like this in a model:

```
public function featuredTopSight($count=8)
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sight::class)
        ->wherePublish(1)
        ->latest()
        ->take($count);
}
```

and then, In view:

```
$sight->featuredTopSight(8);
```

But I got this error:

```
"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

but with `$sight->featuredTopSight;` I got right answer. but I can not pass the parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to share your full view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that function you're defining a relationship.

You can't call a relationship with arguments.

First you need to declare the relation, and then the query or method to retrieve results.

Your method should be something similar to:

```
public function sights()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sight::class);
}

public function getFeaturedTopSights($count = 8)
{
    return $this->sights()->wherePublish(1)->latest()->take($count)->get();
}
```